# MySQL - Altering Column Types

Tags: mysql, sql

Using MySQL, given a table (named "Table1") with 3 known named columns (E.G "Column1", "Column2" and "Column3") and an unknown number of unknown named columns, how could you set the type of all unknown columns to varchar(40) with a SQL statement(s)?

Comment: Um, why?  Is this homework?  `Dynamic SQL` is the only way I could think of without writing out all the column names...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just generate the statements you need and run them

```
select concat('alter table ',  table_name, ' modify column ', column_name, ' VARCHAR(40)') from information_schema.columns  
where table_schema='yourdb' and table_name='table1' 
and column_name NOT IN('col1','col2','col3')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any such sql statement that could do that, but you could write a short program that would query the column names from Table1 and then build the ALTER sql command to set all columns to varchar(40).